# $filter failure after Angular 1.4 upgrade (UI-Bootstrap typeahead)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKz74fDoWY8VmYWR8cgI?p=preview) with examples.

In Angular 1.4 a [change has been introduced](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9992) for `$filter('filter')` to throw an error when it doesn't operate on an array.

The problem with this is that [UI Bootstrap's typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) used this to query and filter async results.

```
// controller
$scope.getActors = function(val) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    var values = [
      {label: 'Jeff Goldblum', value: 1},
      {label: 'Casey Affleck', value: 2},
      {label: 'Tom Cruise', value: 3}
    ];

    // fake an async call
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve(values);
    }, 1500)

    return promise;
}

// directive
typeahead="actor as actor.label for actor in getActors($viewValue) | filter:{label:$viewValue}"
```

However, this now throws an error because what is returned before any results is a `$promise` object, causing `$filter('filter')` to fail.

I thought maybe I could wrap `filter` in another filter to return an empty array before the promise was resolved, but no such luck.

```
// filter
.filter('asyncFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(val) {
    return angular.isArray(val) ? $filter('filter')(val) : [];
  };
})

// directive
typeahead="actor as actor.label for actor in getActors($viewValue) | asyncFilter:{label:$viewValue}"
```

Comment: What about using `$filter` within `getActors()`?

Comment: show the code for `getActors`. Make sure it returns array. Also be sure to upgrade angular-ui

Comment: @charlietfl Added `getActors`.  Using the most up-to-date angular-ui (13.04).

Comment: @AnidMonsur Oh man, I overlooked the simple, elegant answer.  Thanks!  (If you submit it as an official answer I will accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$filter` directly in your `getActors()` function, like so. Also just FYI, $timeout returns a promise, so you don't need to use deferreds in the fake example :)

```
$scope.getActors = function(val) {
    var values = [
      {label: 'Jeff Goldblum', value: 1},
      {label: 'Casey Affleck', value: 2},
      {label: 'Tom Cruise', value: 3}
    ];

    // fake an async call
    return $timeout(function() {
      return values;
    }, 1500).then(function(results) {
        return $filter('filter')(results, {
          label: val
        });
    });
}
```